# Implemented model network but neither training error nor val error decreasing

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, trainingloss

Since I'm novice to Pytorch, this question might be a very trivial one, but I'd like to ask for your help about how to solve this one.

I've implemented one network from a paper and used all hyper parameters and all layers described in the paper.

But when it starts training, even though I set the learning rate decay as 0.001, the errors didn't go down. Training errors goes around 3.3~3.4 and test errors around 3.5~3.6 during 100 epochs..!

I could change the hyperparameters to improve the model, but since the paper told exact numbers, I'd like to see whether there's an error in the training code that I've implemented.

The code below is the code that I used for training.

```
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn 
import json
import torch
import math
import time
import os 

model = nn.Sequential(Baseline(), Classification(40)).to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.999))
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=20, gamma=0.5)

batch = 32

train_path = '/content/mtrain'
train_data = os.listdir(train_path)

test_path = '/content/mtest'
test_data = os.listdir(test_path)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch, shuffle=True)

train_loss, val_loss = [], []
epochs = 100

now = time.time()
print('training start!')
for epoch in range(epochs):

  running_loss = 0.0

  for bidx, trainb32 in enumerate(train_loader):

    bpts, blabel = [], []
    
    for i, data in enumerate(trainb32):
      path = os.path.join(train_path, data)
      
      with open(path, 'r') as f:
        jdata = json.load(f)
      
      label = jdata['label']
      pts = jdata['pts']

      bpts.append(pts) 
      blabel.append(label)

    bpts = torch.tensor(bpts).transpose(1, 2).to(device)
    blabel = torch.tensor(blabel).to(device)
    
    input = data_aug(bpts).to(device)

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    y_pred, feat_stn, glob_feat = model(input)
    # print(f'global_feat is {global_feat}')
    loss = F.nll_loss(y_pred, blabel) + 0.001 * regularizer(feat_stn)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    running_loss += loss.item()

    if bidx % 10 == 9:
      vrunning_loss = 0
      vacc = 0
      model.eval()
      with torch.no_grad():
        
        # val batch
        for vbidx, testb32 in enumerate(test_loader):
          bpts, blabel = [], []
          
          for j, data in enumerate(testb32):
            path = os.path.join(test_path, data)
            
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
              jdata = json.load(f)
            
            label = jdata['label']
            pts = jdata['pts']

            bpts.append(pts) 
            blabel.append(label)

          bpts = torch.tensor(bpts).transpose(1, 2).to(device)
          blabel = torch.tensor(blabel).to(device)
          
          input = data_aug(bpts).to(device)
          vy_pred, vfeat_stn, vglob_feat = model(input)
          # print(f'global_feat is {vglob_feat}')
          vloss = F.nll_loss(vy_pred, blabel) + 0.001 * regularizer(vfeat_stn)
          _, vy_max = torch.max(vy_pred, dim=1) 
          vy_acc = torch.sum(vy_max == blabel) / batch
          
          vacc += vy_acc
          vrunning_loss += vloss

      # print every training 10th batch
      train_loss.append(running_loss / len(train_loader))
      val_loss.append(vrunning_loss / len(test_loader))

      print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs} {bidx}/{len(train_loader)}.. "
            f"Train loss: {running_loss / 10:.3f}.."
            f"Val loss: {vrunning_loss / len(test_loader):.3f}.."
            f"Val Accuracy: {vacc/len(test_loader):.3f}.."
            f"Time: {time.time() - now}")
      now = time.time()
      running_loss = 0
      model.train()
      
          
print(f'training finish! training time is {time.time() - now}')
print(model.parameters())

savePath = '/content/modelpath.pth'
torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/content/modelpath.pth')
```

Sorry for the basic question, but if there's no error in this training code, it would be very pleasure to let me know and if there is, please give any hint to solve..

I've implemented pointNet code and the full code is available at https://github.com/RaraKim/PointNet/blob/master/PointNet_pytorch.ipynb

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please create [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) custom class for your data which returns tensors instead of paths. You put it into `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. Also code for your model would be nice to have. Also loss for multiclass is usually [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) as it's more numerically stable, but you shouldn't use any activation at the end in such case. You can edit this question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code, and I believe that you have some tensors that are manually declared. In torch tensors the default value of the ***"requires_grad"*** flag is  ***False***. And I think hence your backpropagation isn't working correctly, can you try to fix that? I will be happy to help you further if the issue still persists.